# window.open onclick specific post with permalink

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

When I click on the post it opens a random post instead of the post I clicked.

> The `$postid = get_the_ID();` is in the beginning of my code.

Here's the function i use inside the `onlick=''` that is inside the `<a>` tag which is around the post image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function wholeAd(){
        var permalink = '<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>';
        window.open(permalink, 'newwindow', 'width=900, height=650');
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div class="ad-box span3">
    <a class="ad-image" onclick='wholeAd()'>
```

Comment: how are you passing the $postid?

Comment: I have it on the top of the page, where get_header is. and use it in the get_permalink parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution:

You don't have to make a function

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" onclick="window.open(this.href,'newwindow', 'width=900, height=650');return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

For Popup you can use something like this

```
"<a href='javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(&#39;"+oListItem.get_item('Url').get_url()+"&#39;, &#39;NotificationCallback&#39;, "+oListItem.get_item('Width')+", "+oListItem.get_item('Height')+",&#39;" + oListItem.get_item('Title') + "&#39;);'>&nbsp;" + oListItem.get_item('Title') + "</a>"
```

for New Window you can use something like this

```
<a target='_blank' href='url' style='styles'>Title</a>
```

Hope this helps, Mark it as answer if it solves your query